# Biconditionality of the compatibility theorem for commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator

The compatibility theorem states that, if the operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ representing the observables $A$ and $B$ do commute, then there exists a common eigenbasis for their eigenstates, and those observables are compatible.

I wonder if this theorem is biconditional: would it be possible to find a common eigenbasis of eigenstates for a pair if $A$ and $B$ do not commute? Or is the *if* of the theorem actually an *if and only if*, and the condition that they commute is both necessary and sufficient?

Comment: Hint: To see why the reverse statement holds true, expand a generic state in a common eigenbasis of $A$ and $B$ and compute the commutator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is if and only if. Given two observables $X$ and $Y$:

1. $[X,Y]=0$
2. $X$ and $Y$ have a common eigenbasis

are equivalent statements.